# Sending a GET request using PHP and Curl outputs Question marks

Tags: php, curl

I think this is an encoding problem and I tried everything I can think of. This is my simple code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://theatrevazrajdane.bg/%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%8A%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8/2",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  // CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

So far I tied:

- Sending it with and without the CURLOPT_ENCODING parameter
- Sending it with and without "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Sending this from Insomnia with the following parameters it works just fine.

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://theatrevazrajdane.bg/%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%8A%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8/2 \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

From Insomnia for example I get the Title of the page as `<title>Актьори |  Театър Възраждане</title>`, but sending this from PHP using cURL I am getting `<title>������� |  ������ ����������</title>`

Comment: Possibly the HTML page you're echoing it into from cURL doesn't have any utf-8 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Content-Type` header of the website you mentioned:

`Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251;`

This is the encoding in which the returned string is: `windows-1251`.

Either give this when you return your own content to the browser or:

1. Use `iconv` to convert the encoding to UTF-8:

```php
$convertedResponse = iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $response);
```

2. Use `mb_convert_encoding` to convert the encoding to UTF-8:

```php
$convertedResponse = mb_convert_encoding($response, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251');
```

Comment: Because I have some pages that are utf-8 encoding, so I simply added this code before the $response and it works like a charm. `if (str_contains($response, 'charset="windows-1251"')) { $response = mb_convert_encoding($response, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251'); }`